# How at add files in data($HOME) folder for BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry-10

I am trying to add few writable files in data folder of file system provided by BlackBerry 10 simulator.
PFB file system hierarchy in link provided : https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/filesystem/index.html

In bar-descriptor.xml file tried below option but not succeeded in any one of them.
 1. $HOME/jsapp.html
 2. ${HOME}/jsapp.html

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question, but it sounds like you are trying to include thos files in the BAR file. You can't do this. All assets deployed with the BAR file are covered by the application signature and can't be changed (other than on the simulator or a device with a developer token with an unsigned BAR). If you need to modify an asset after installation you deploy the initial version with the BAR file and copy it to the data directory. One of the sample programs (the quote database sample if I remember correctly) does this.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard said, this is directly from the Quotes sample app

```
    void CustomSqlDataSource::copyFileToDataFolder(const QString fileName)
{
    // Since we need read and write access to the file, it has
    // to be moved to a folder where we have access to it. First,
    // we check if the file already exists (previously copied).
    QString dataFolder = QDir::homePath();
    QString newFileName = dataFolder + "/" + fileName;
    QFile newFile(newFileName);


    if (!newFile.exists()) {
        // If the file is not already in the data folder, we copy it from the
        // assets folder (read only) to the data folder (read and write).
        QString appFolder(QDir::homePath());
        appFolder.chop(4);
        QString originalFileName = appFolder + "app/native/assets/" + fileName;
        QFile originalFile(originalFileName);

        if (originalFile.exists()) {
            // Create sub folders if any creates the SQL folder for a file path like e.g. sql/quotesdb
            QFileInfo fileInfo(newFileName);
            QDir().mkpath (fileInfo.dir().path());

            if(!originalFile.copy(newFileName)) {
                qDebug() << "Failed to copy file to path: " << newFileName;
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Failed to copy file data base file does not exists.";
        }
    }

    mSourceInDataFolder = newFileName;
}
```